# Inbox of iOS Gmail App Not Syncing on iPad

Tags: ipad, gmail

I have installed the Gmail app for iPad, and configured my gmail account. However, the inbox does not sync at all. It always shows 'No offline messages'. But I am able to see the messages under All Mail and Important labels. I have enabled the POP and IMAP settings for my gmail account (under settings).

Please help me resolve the issue so that my inbox syncs up automatically. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method for syncing your GMail account with an iOS device is by using Exchange with Google Sync. I could detail the directions here, but Google has a [great writeup](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) that is far more robust.

If you have multiple calendars you'll want to follow [this guide](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139206) to configure your device to access them as well.

Comment: I am not using the mail client provided by default in iPad, I am using the iOS Gmail App (from App Store). I like it better. Is there a solution?

Comment: Gmail began changing its recommendations recently I noticed -- they say to prefer the gmail app over exchange. Which they're attempting to phase out -- in fact  the exchange sync is  currenltly quite broken on windows desktops with newer versions of  outlook.  They're recommending the cardav and caldav for contacts/calendar sync with ios also

Comment: Are you using 2-factor auth? Needs application-specific password.  Otherwise try signing out/reauth or even reinstall.